# Excel Web Add In Invalid Operation on Range.Load Function

Tags: javascript, excel

I developed a Web AddIn that communicates with an API and loads or saves values in an Excel Cell depending on their CellName.

Problem is that in a different file I get **Invalid Operation** Errors on the Load Function of a Range.
My Question is now how do I find out why this specific file gives me this error.

Here is some Code that is more or less a copy of the Microsoft Example.

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
            var sheetName = "sheetname";
            var cellkey = "Projektname";
            var worksheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheetName);
            let cellKey = "Projektname";
            let names = ctx.workbook.names;
            let range = names.getItem(cellKey).getRange();
            range.load("cellCount");
            return ctx.sync().then(function () {
                console.log(range.cellCount);
            });
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
            if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
            }
        });
```

---

This is the Error Object as JSON (I Can translate the german if it is necessary)

```
{
    "description": "Dieser Vorgang ist für das aktuelle Objekt nicht zulässig.",
    "name": "RichApi.Error",
    "code": "InvalidOperation",
    "traceMessages": [],
    "innerError": null,
    "debugInfo": {
        "code": "InvalidOperation",
        "message": "Dieser Vorgang ist für das aktuelle Objekt nicht zulässig.",
        "errorLocation": "NamedItem.getRange",
        "statement": "var range=name.getRange();",
        "surroundingStatements": ["var workbook=context.workbook;", "var worksheets=workbook.worksheets;", "var worksheet=worksheets.getItem(...);", "var names=workbook.names;", "var name=names.getItem(...);", "// >>>>>", "var range=name.getRange();", "// <<<<<", "// Instantiate {range}", "range.load([\\" cellCount \\ "]);"],
        "fullStatements": ["Please enable config.extendedErrorLogging to see full statements."]
    },
    "stack": "InvalidOperation: Dieser Vorgang ist für das aktuelle Objekt nicht zulässig.\\n   at Anonymous function (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.js:24:283976)\\n   at r (https://c
    dnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.4/bluebird.min.js:31:6804)\\n   at r.prototype._settlePromiseFromHandler (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.4/bluebird.min.js:30:12222)\\n   at r.prototype._settlePromise (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.4/bluebird.min.js:30:13027)\\n   at r.prototype._settlePromise0 (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.4/bluebird.min.js:30:13728)\\n   at r.prototype._settlePromises (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.4/bluebird.min.js:30:15058)\\n   at r.prototype._drainQueue (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.4/bluebird.min.js:29:2939)\\n   at r.prototype._drainQueues (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.4/bluebird.min.js:29:2997)\\n   at drainQueues (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.4/bluebird.min.js:29:1211)\\n   at Anonymous function (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.4/bluebird.min.js:30:28770)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found the Problem,
The Named Reference was not valid. 
After deleting the Named Reference in the Manger and then readding it to the Cell everything worked again.